# FLUTTER : any Solution to this Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, dart

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
  >   Skipped due to earlier error
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 35s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

I recently install back my flutter after I reset my PC and this message keep poping up eventhough I just created new project, any solution to this would be helpful.thx

Answer (score 2):

from this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30573)
seems like you need to make sure your dependencies are not conflicting /same versions.

You can update or lower your dependencies version if you changed any before this error occured, run `flutter clean` and finally `flutter run`

Comment: how to do update or lower my dependencies, sorry im still new at this

Comment: open a file `pubspec.yaml` and you will find your dependencies here. Read more about it here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Answer (score 1):

First add mavenCentral() in project level Build.gradle and then connect your pc to USA VPN and then Run.